# WIndows Firewall policy wireguard

Tags: windows, firewall, wireguard, windows-server-2022

I don't know if it's possible, but I have a VPN with Wireguard on a Server 2022, configured with this:

https://github.com/micahmo/WgServerforWindows

It works correctly, but I would like to know how I can do so that a client can only access a specific IP address of the VPN and not all as it currently does.

On the client side I can configure AllowedIPs but it is modifiable by the user, I am interested in doing it on the server.

I had thought about doing it with the Windows Firewall, but I don't know how. I have done some test adding a new rule and blocking the private IP of the VPN client but with unsatisfactory result.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the Windows Firewall for this, as WG does not bring such a ruleset-feature to the table. Check the "Outgoing connections" section and set rules for the IP-Range of your WG Clients.